# A bag contains 6 white balls, 5 black balls and 2 red balls.

Tags: probability

A bag contains 6 white balls, 5 black balls and 2 red balls.
If two balls are drawn at random, what is the probability that neither of them are white?

For this question, the method that I used was to consider the four possible cases, BB, RR, BR, RB.

Therefore $$P = P(BB)+P(RR)+P(BR)+P(RB)=\frac{5}{13} \times \frac{4}{12} + \frac{2}{13} \times \frac{1}{12} + \frac{5}{13} \times \frac{2}{12} + \frac{2}{13} \times \frac{5}{12} = \frac{7}{26} $$

which gives the correct answer, but I found there are two other ways to do this question, neither of which I understand.

Alternative method 1):

$P = P(\text{red/black first pick}) \times P(\text{red/black second pick})
=\frac{5+2}{13} \times \frac{(5+2)-1}{13-1} = \frac{7}{26}$

This obviously kind of makes sense, but I've just never seen a question done this way before, I would appreciate if someone could explain logic behind this.

Alternative method 2)
$$P = \frac{{}_5C{}_2 + {}_2C{}_2 + {}_5C{}_1 \times {}_2C{}_1}{_{13}C{}_2}=\frac{7}{26}$$

What I don't understand about this method is why we didn't view BR and RB as two different cases, i.e., why we didn't do

$$P = \frac{{}_5C{}_2 + {}_2C{}_2 + {}_5C{}_1 \times {}_2C{}_1 + {}_2C{}_1 \times {}_5C{}_1 }{_{13}C{}_2} $$

Comment: In alt method 1, we are clubbing together black and red i, and sine there are $7$ total such out of $13$, in an abbreviated way, we find the ans as $\frac7{13}\frac6{12}$  (since all we are interested in is that we don't get white)

Comment: In alt method $2$, using combinations implies that you have one red, one black in any order, so you needn't multiply by $2$, which you need to do for your original method.